# Change URL in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that stores static paths of image cache files we keep. Something like:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/img/cache/24295839.jpg
```

is stored hundreds of thousands of times. We recently switched to SSL and need to create some type of script to change all of the http to https in the database.

The field is:

```
cached_file_url
```

I don't know where to start with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in one simple query.

```
UPDATE table
SET cached_file_url = REPLACE(cached_file_url, 'http://', 'https://')
WHERE cached_file_url LIKE 'http://%'
```

You should familiarize yourself with MySQL string functions (or at least know where to look when you have questions like this).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

You can do a lot of the sorts of string manipulations you might commonly do in a programming language within MySQL itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  cached_file_url = CONCAT('https://',
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(cached_file_url, 'http://', -1))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa206c/1).

Comment: This won't destroy the whole URL path will it?

Comment: @JDAudi if all urls begins with http:// this won't destroy the whole URL, but if they don't it's better to add a where condition, like in mike brant's answer